# Brightness level: Adjusting from Xbox 360 or TV

Tags: xbox-360, monitor

I generally increase the brightness level for each game. If the slider is in the middle of the bar, I move it till the half way to the end (in other words,  2/4 to 3/4). Should I leave it as it is (2/4) and increase the brightness level of the TV? Which option is better in terms of quality of display?

My TV is a full HD Sony KDL 40" LCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually modify this per game. This is mainly because I have set the levels on the TV for cable as well as netflix/other videos on the Xbox the way I like it. I would rather customize each game (some I may want to be darker than others) than adjust it each time on the TV that I want to play or watch something.